# GPSの情報を距離間隔で取得したい

Tags: android, kotlin, gps

AndroidアプリをKotlinで作成中ですが、FusedLocationProviderClientを利用してGPSの情報を一定の距離間隔で取得したいのですがうまく取得できません。
希望値のため正確にならないのは当然ですが10mを指定しても50m以上になったりします。
設定を間違えていますでしょうか
ご指摘いただければ幸いです、よろしくお願いします。

```
private fun createLocationRequest(): LocationRequest? {
    return LocationRequest.create()?.apply {
        setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        setSmallestDisplacement(10F)
        //setFastestInterval(100000)
        //setInterval(5000)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setSmallestDisplacement`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#public-locationrequest-setsmallestdisplacement-float-smallestdisplacementmeters)

このメソッドは

> Set the minimum displacement between location updates in meters

**最大値**ではなく**最小値**を設定するわけですから、

> 10mを指定しても50m以上になった

は全く仕様通りで問題はないです。